# why combobox pass one value every time?

Tags: php

As you can see in the below PHP code, I am going to get the value for a combobox from a database table. It shows all the columns of the table without any problem, but when I want to pass the value of combobox back to a table, it always passes the value `1`. Why?

```
<?php
$leccom = mysql_query("select Lec_ID, Lec_Name from lecturer") or die(mysql_error());

while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($leccom)) {
    $name = $result[Lec_Name];
    $id_leccom = $result[Lec_ID];
    echo "<option value='$id_leccom'> $name</option>";
}

?>
```

Next file:

```
<?php
mysql_select_db('lms', mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')) or die(mysql_error());

// Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }

    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

// Sanitize the POST values

$filedesc = clean($_POST['pdesc']);
$fname = clean($_POST['Pre_Name']);
$com = clean($_post[$id_Leccom]);
echo $_post['comselection'];

// $subject= clean($_POST['upname']);
// upload random name/number

$rd2 = mt_rand(1000, 9999) . "_File";

// Check that we have a file

if ((!empty($_FILES["uploaded_file"])) && ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0))
{

    // Check if the file is JPEG image and it's size is less than 350Kb

    $filename = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
    if (($ext != "exe") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] != "application/x-msdownload"))
    {

        // Determine the path to which we want to save this file
        // $newname = dirname(__FILE__).'/upload/'.$filename;

        $newname = "uploads/" . $rd2 . "-" . $filename;

        // Check if the file with the same name is already exists on the server
        // Attempt to move the uploaded file to it's new place

        if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $newname)))
        {

            // successful upload
            // echo "It's done! The file has been saved as: ".$newname;
            // echo "$filedesc,$newname,$fname,$comlec";

            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `lms`.`presentation` (`Pre_Name` ,`Path` ,`PLec_ID` ,`pdatein` ,`pdesc`) values ('$fname','$newname','1',NOW(),'$filedesc')") or die("failed");

            // mysql_query("INSERT INTO presentation (pdesc,path,pdatein,Pre_Name,plec_id) VALUES ('$filedesc','$newname',NOW(),'$fname','$comlec')") or die("query failed");
            // mysql_query("INSERT INTO presentation ('pdesc','path','Pre_Name','PLec_ID') values ('$filedesc','$newname','$fname','$comlec')") ;

            header("location: fileupload.php");
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $name = $result['Lec_Name'];
   $id_leccom = $result['Lec_ID'];
```

and

```
   echo "<option value='".$id_leccom."'>$name</option>";
```

Comment: @user2784585 your   table def ?